# How do I use this function for saving and loading with pickle?

Tags: python-3.x, function, pickle

I am trying to save content for my small project I am doing and wanted to test out saving. I get quite far until I make my loading function. I'll show both saving and loading:

```
    def saving(slot1, slot2, slot3) :

     if saving == slot1 :
       pickle.dump(name, open("save1.sav", "wb"))
     elif saving == slot2 :
      pickle.dump(name, open("save2.sav", "wb"))
     elif saving == slot3 :
      pickle.dump(name, open("save3.sav", "wb"))

    def loading(file1, file2, file3) :

     if loading == file1 :
      loading = pickle.load(name, open("save1.sav", "rb"))
     elif loading == file2 :
      loading = pickle.load(name, open("save2.sav", "rb"))
     elif loading == file3 :
      loading = pickle.load(name, open("save3.sav", "rb"))
```

My saving function is fine and works, but when I call my loading and specify

```
    loading(file1)
```

It tells me:

```
    NameError: name 'file1' is not defined
```

If this is just a simple misunderstanding of how Python functions work, lead me to a place where I can learn about them. If you have no issues, let me know and I'll see what I can redo in my program.

Answer (score 1):

try to do all the define the `file1` inside `__main__` function. To be honest, This question is still lack of information on where you create the `file1`.

Also try to remove the empty line between your `def loading` and the content. OR add one more empty line AFTER the `def saving` content

Python code runs from top to bottom. If you call the the `loading` before the `file1` it will said that the `file1` is not defined. It also line sensitive as well. The more you create an empty line it may considered it out of scope.

Your pickle code is fine, but the way you define the `file1` from outside the function may cause the problem.

Try to debug from this link I've found.
[Here](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-nameerror-name-is-not-defined/#:%7E:text=A%20NameError%20is%20raised%20when,wanted%20the%20variable%20to%20do.)